# When iterating through an array in Swift, is there a reference the index/iteration of the loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, swift, indexer

Say I have the following code:

```
var array = [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4]

for item in array {
    println(index)
}
```

Is there a way to access what iteration the loop is on within the loop's body? (i.e.: 0, 1, 2, 3...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var array = [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4]

for (index,item) in enumerate(array) {
    println("\(index): \(item)")
}
```

Comment: This is the way that Apple advertised!

Comment: @JackWu Exactly, I knew Apple mentioned something about this. Thanks Christian!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a count variable. Other than that, you need to use a regular for loop.